# Prove or disprove $\lim_{K \to\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty}E(\min(X_n,K))=E(X)$ when $X_n$ surely converges to $X$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

The Question:

> Let $X, X_1, X_2, ...$ be non-negative random variables, defined jointly on some probability triple $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbf P)$, each having finite expected value. Assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$. For $n$, $K \in \mathbf N$, let $Y_{n,K}=\min(X_n,K)$. For each of the following statements, either prove it must be true, or provide a counter-example to show it is sometimes false.
>
> (a)  $\lim_{K \to\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty}E(Y_{n,K})=E(X)$
>
> (b)  $\lim_{n \to\infty} \lim_{K\to\infty}E(Y_{n,K})=E(X)$

---

I don't even know where to start. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints for (a):**

1. Use the dominated convergence theorem to show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(Y_{n,K}) = \mathbb{E}(\min\{X,K\}).$$
2. It follows from step 1 that (a) is equivalent to $$\lim_{K \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(\min\{X,K\}) = \mathbb{E}(X). \tag{1}$$
3. Apply the monotone convergence theorem to prove $(1)$.

**Hints for (b):**

1. Use the dominated convergence theorem to show that $$\lim_{K \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(Y_{n,K}) = \mathbb{E}(X_n).$$
2. By step 1, (b) is equivalent to $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(X_n) = \mathbb{E}(X). \tag{2}$$
3. Try to find a counterexample to $(2)$ (e.g. a sequence such that $X_n \to 0$ almost surely, but $\mathbb{E}(X_n)=1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can I ask you $min(X_n,K) \to min(X,K)$ almost surely? If so, is it a property of surely convergence? I think this condition is needed for the dominated convergence theorem

Comment: @Y.Kim Yes, it is. If $X_n \to X$ almost surely, then $f(X_n) \to f(X)$ almost surely for any continuous function $f$.

Comment: thank you so much!! I solved it by following your hints.

Comment: @Y.Kim You are welcome. If you find the answer helpful, you can accept/upvote it by clicking on the tick/up arrow next to it.